# Olympiad Chessboard Problem

Tags: contest-math

I am stumped by this contest math training problem from South Africa:

> Consider an 8 × 8 chessboard with the bottom left 3 × 3 squares
> occupied by cute little frogs. Each cute frog can jump over any frog
> adjacent to it, vertically or horizontally, to land on another square
> two squares away from where it started. Is it possible by repeating
> this operation to get all the cute frogs to the top right 3 × 3
> squares?

I am wondering what kind of characteristic is associated with this setup. I tried parity and colouring, but to no success.

Comment: You can find a colouring argument – try to find invariants of how a frog moves.

Comment: Can you please provide the source ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Color the columns black and white alternately.

Frogs from black squares can only move to other black squares. Now count the number of black squares in the bottom left $3\times 3$  and in the top right $3\times 3$

Comment: Very nice! Notice that frogs can move also diagonaly and this still works.

Comment: @nonuser But saying so divulges the solution of course.